# Constants - how to declare?

Tags: php

Im using php 5.3 and wish to declare a constant only to be used in my class using:

```
const numOfFoo;
```

Is there any conventions to consider with const var names, ie, all caps?

Also is this the correct way to declare it, should I be using private/protected?

Comment: Use all caps for all constants, even in classes. Class constants are always public so you do not need to use `public` when declaring them (and would get a syntax error if you do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your constant like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    const CONSTANT = 'constant value';

    function showConstant() {
        echo  self::CONSTANT . "\n";
    }
}
```

You cannot declare the visibility of your class constant:

> It may seem obvious, but class constants are always publicly visible.
>   They cannot be made private or protected. *([See here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php#108944)).*

And it's good practice and following most conventions to use uppercase terms (with underscore), but not required.

Comment: Thanks, how should I declare it, all capitals?

Comment: It's good practice to use uppercase terms, but not required.

Comment: Sigh, please comment downvotes. (Or is this just a way to advantage your answers?)

Comment: I thought you gave a good answer.

Comment: Thanks, that was my intention :)

Answer (score 1):

assing a value,
`const NUM_OF_FOO = 'something';`

the value a constant never change, why you need constant empty?

[php constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)

Answer (score 1):

Normal convention says const should be all caps.

It is a good idea to have constants to be public, so that it can be used a reference variable

Comment: Constants are always public.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally recognised PHP convention that constants are always defined entirely with upper case names. This applies equally to class constants.

For instance, the [PSR-1 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) (one of various PHP coding standards guidelines) says this:

> Class constants MUST be declared in all upper case with underscore separators.

Furthermore, PHP constants are always and can only be public. Defining their visibility is not possible.

Comment: So my var should be: NUM_OF_FOO ?

Comment: @panthro From the same PSR-1 document, "Class constants MUST be declared in all upper case with underscore separators." So yes, that's  a good convention.

Comment: Downvoter, comments are polite.